# Difference between joint probability and mutual information on a Venn Diagram

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

We all know the usual Venn diagram for mutual information:

[image]

source [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information#/media/File:Entropy-mutual-information-relative-entropy-relation-diagram.svg).

The visualization and description of joint entropy H(X,Y) make it appear as though it is the same as mutual information I(X;Y), which of course it is not.

For example, we know that joint probability is the intersection of two events, and is where both **circles overlap each other**.

But mutual information is also where **both circles overlap each other**.

Wikipedia says the joint entropy is "the area contained by both circles." But this is also the mutual information.

Why is joint entropy and mutual information being depicted the same way?

Answer (score 3):

> Wikipedia says the joint entropy is "the area contained by both circles." But this is also the mutual information.

No. The joint entropy is the area enclosed by the **union** of both circles. The mutual information is the **intersection**.

This alternative diagram (from MacKay's Information Theory,
Inference, and Learning Algorithms) can help:
[image]

Comment: But the joint probability is known to be the intersection, not the union. Why would the joint entropy, which is presumably based off the joint probability, be a union in this case?

Comment: Those circles are not really Venn diagrams, they don't represent sets or probabilities. It's merely a mnemonic, to help to learn (via the areas) the relationships between those quantities, like eg $H(X,Y) = H(X) + H(Y |X)$ or $I(X,Y) = H(X)-H(X|Y)$.

Comment: I think the reason is that the event hasn’t been specified and therefore the joint probability expands the full area enclosed by the circles (and is thus a union not an intersection). For example, if we drew the Venn for the event of getting all red sixes, we would have the 4 sixes in one circle and 26 red cards in the other circle, with the joint probability being the intersection enclosing only the red sixes. But if we do NOT specify the event then the joint probability encloses the entire union between variables.

Answer (score -1):

This [venn diagram from Thomas and Cover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B018h.jpg)

[image]

is slightly different than the one you posted above in that it has arrows making it clearer that $H(X,Y)$ is apparently not the middle portion of the Venn Diagram and instead the union of X and Y as described in the answer by leonbloy.  I agree this is confusing since I am used to seeing $p(X,Y)$ which is defined as the intersection.