# Geometric Interpretation of negativity of interaction information

Tags: information-theory, entropy, mutual-information

The [interaction information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_information) (II) in 3D is defined as a generalization of the 2D [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) (MI).

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
I(X:Y:Z)
&=& I(X:Y) - I(X:Y|Z) \\
&=& H(X) + H(Y)+H(Z) - H(XY) - H(XZ) - H(YZ) + H(XYZ)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

II can be negative, for example for $Z = \mathrm{XOR}(X, Y)$. It is easy to convince oneself of this fact by simply calculating all terms for the XOR example and confirming that it is indeed negative.

My question is about the geometric interpretation of this fact. The [multivariate mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_mutual_information) is typically illustrated by [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_mutual_information#/media/File:VennInfo3Var.svg) three-way Venn diagram, where the entropies of each variable (which are positive quantities) are subdivided into shared and unique parts. Naively looking at this diagram it feels like each slice of a positive quantity should also be a positive quantity. How is it possible that the centre piece of this diagram is negative geometrically? Where does the naive intuition go wrong? Is there something better than a Venn diagram to geometrically illustrate this result?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1219753/312  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1235871/312  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3784383/312 ...

Comment: Thanks. Ok, I agree that Venn diagrams are just not convenient for this purpose. I think I have found a somewhat satisfactory answer using graphs, called partial information decomposition https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.2515. Still very difficult to think about, but I guess it is just the fundamental difficulty of the problem rather than lack of good visualization